# Showing a fourth rank tensor in $\epsilon$'s reduces to one in the metric $g$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Consider the fourth rank tensor $$S_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} = a(\epsilon_{\mu \sigma}\epsilon_{\nu \rho} + \epsilon_{\mu \rho}\epsilon_{\nu \sigma})f(x^2),$$

in 2D where $a$ is a constant and $f(x^2)$ is a Lorentz invariant function (not important for this question).  I want to show this reduces to a linear combination of $g's$, that is to say $$S_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} \equiv (a_1 g_{\mu \nu}g_{\rho \sigma}  + a_2 (g_{\mu \rho}g_{\nu \sigma} + g_{\mu \sigma}g_{\nu \rho}))f(x^2)$$

This is in a context of 2D Conformal field theory, so each index takes only the value 1 or 2. To do this explicitly, write out all possibilities.  When $\mu = 1,2$ we have that the original expression reduces to $$\epsilon_{1 \sigma}\epsilon_{\nu \rho} + \epsilon_{1 \rho}\epsilon_{\nu \sigma} + \epsilon_{2 \sigma}\epsilon_{\nu \rho} + \epsilon_{2 \rho}\epsilon_{\nu \sigma}.$$  Now I want to consider the values of $\nu=1,2$. I have been told that I should get another four terms by expanding the above taking into consideration the values of $\nu$.  But it seems to me that I would have six terms.  To illustrate my problem, I could obtain the additional terms $$\epsilon_{1 \sigma}\epsilon_{1 \rho} + \epsilon_{1 \rho}\epsilon_{1 \sigma} + \epsilon_{2 \sigma}\epsilon_{1\rho} + \epsilon_{2 \rho}\epsilon_{1 \sigma}$$ or $$ \epsilon_{1 \sigma}\epsilon_{2 \rho} + \epsilon_{1 \rho}\epsilon_{2 \sigma} + \epsilon_{2 \sigma}\epsilon_{2 \rho} + \epsilon_{2 \rho}\epsilon_{2 \sigma}.$$  But I notice that two of the terms are common in these expressions, so should I not have an expansion of the form $$\epsilon_{1 \sigma}\epsilon_{1 \rho} + \epsilon_{1 \rho}\epsilon_{1 \sigma} + \epsilon_{2 \sigma}\epsilon_{1\rho} + \epsilon_{2 \rho}\epsilon_{1 \sigma}  + \epsilon_{2 \sigma}\epsilon_{2 \rho} + \epsilon_{2 \rho}\epsilon_{2 \sigma}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent at least 5 minutes decoding what the question could be. Finally, I realized that the question says "When $\mu=1,2$..." and it writes an expression in which sometimes the value $1$ is substituted for $\mu$ in the first expression (not "equation"), sometimes the value $2$. You can't have both of them. If the free index $\mu=1$, then it cannot be that $\mu=2$, and at any rate, all the four original terms always have the same value of $\mu$. Because it's homework, I don't think it's right to tell you more than one mistake.

Comment: Oh sorry, there is an error in the opening equation, I have corrected it and hopefully things make more sense.  Please feel free to elaborate/edit your post, this is not at all homework, but rather a homework-like question that another user tagged because of the connotations that come with the description alongside 'homework'.

Comment: Sorry, I still see the same error in the equation after "When $\mu=1,2$"

Comment: I write out $S_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ for the case when $\mu=1$ and then added this to the case when $\mu=2$ (modulo the constants and Lorentz-invariant functions)  That is where my four terms are coming from in the equation 'after $\mu=1,2$'.  If this is incorrect, then would you please be able to clarify my starting point in your answer? The full exercise can be found in Di Francesco, P.108/110.  I am simply trying to fill in some steps as I read through. Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do you "add" terms with $\mu=1$ to the terms with $\mu=2$? Imagine that 1 stands for "apples" and 2 stands for "oranges". (The index $\mu$ only appears once so there is no summation rule over it.) Then you are adding apples and oranges, right? Your starting point and DiFrancesco's book is correct. It's just the whole solution of yours starting with "When $\mu=1,2$" that makes no sense.

Comment: Please see the last few posts in this thread http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=763586 that is what I am following - is it incorrect?

Comment: Yes, strangerep seems to have the same error like you somewhere in that page.

Comment: Ok, so how should I begin to show that the form of the tensor involving epsilons reduces to one involving a linear combination of metric terms?

Comment: You may do it a component by component, if you really want it explicitly, but you must do it right and avoid conflating the components in bizarre ways. Because of the antisymmetry of the epsilon, the nonzero elements of $S$ only occur for $\mu\sigma\nu\rho=1212$ or $2112$ or $1221$ or $2121$. You must cbeck that for these arrangements of indices - 4 separate possibilities - they're equal and for all the other values of the indices, the $g$-based formula for $S$ is zero. It's not hard. Note that in all these 4 arrangements, the indices always repeat twice, just like what you need in $gg$.

Comment: The $gg$ formula for $S$ is also apriori nonzero for the arrangement of the indices $1111$ and $2222$ which would be bad, but for an appropriate ratio of the coefficients $a_1/a_2$, this unwanted term cancels.

Comment: Do you mean to say the equations only hold for a specific set of $a, a_1 $ and $a_2$? The only way I can see right now to get the equality to work is to write $$a(\epsilon_{\mu \sigma}\epsilon_{\nu \rho} + \epsilon_{\mu \rho}\epsilon_{\nu \sigma}) = a_1  g_{\mu \nu}g_{\rho \sigma} +a_2(g_{\mu \rho}g_{\nu \sigma} + g_{\mu \sigma}g_{\nu \rho})$$ (result modulo L-invariant f) and with solving the resulting equations by putting in values of $\mu \sigma \nu \rho$ it seems to mean $a_1/a_2 = -2$. If you carried out the calculation yourself, did you obtain the same result? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, $a_1/a_2=-2$ to cancel the 1111 and 2222 terms. It also cancels the 1122 and 2211 terms, of course. You may determine the value of $a$ uniquely out of some nonzero components. Of course, if you rescale $a,a_1,a_2$ by the same factor, it will still be OK - it's still just multiplying the equation by a number.

Comment: Let me say that these tests are only simple in the frame where $g$ is diagonal, with the usual diagonal entries, so for a general coordinate system, you may either run the more general calculation, or you may argue that the objects behave properly under the transformations. In a general system, the most natural fully antisymmetric tensor really has scalar components proportional to $\sqrt{|\det g|}$

Comment: The equations I got out of the four permutations you listed were $a_1 = 2a, a_2 = -a$ and for the permutation 1111 (or 2222) I got the equation $a_1 = -2a_2$.  I thought I could then solve for $a$ uniquely, but it appears the only solution to this is that $a=a_1=a_2=0$.

Comment: You made a mistake.

Comment: I must have, but I didn't find my error: From permutations 1212 and 2121 I get the equation $a_1 = 2a$.  From permutations 1221 and 2112, I get $a_2 = -a$.  From permutation 1111, I get $a_1 + 2a_2 = 0$.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. An error is your conclusion that all the constants vanish. The three equations are clearly not independent, are they? Subtract the last one from the first one, for example.

Comment: I see, so that means I would need more equations to determine $a$ uniquely.

Comment: It's just a normalization factor. Don't get carried away.

Comment: Is there anyway to see by inspection that a form like $$a (x^2)^{-3}( g_{\mu \sigma} x_{\rho} x_{\nu}  + g_{\mu \rho} x_{\sigma} x_{\nu} + g_{\nu \sigma} x_{\rho} x_{\mu}  + g_{\nu \rho} x_{\sigma} x_{\mu} )$$ may be equivalent to $$b (g_{\mu \nu} x_{\rho} x_{\sigma} + g_{\rho \sigma} x_{\mu} x_{\nu})(x^2)^{-3}?$$

Comment: Yes, it is never equal (by equivalent, did you mean equal?). Just substitute $\mu\nu\rho\sigma=1123$ and $x=(0,0,1,1)$, for example. Only $g_{\mu\nu}$ is nonzero among all the metric coefficients, so the first expression is zero while the second is not.